# How to check if the Windows 10 device is connected to a public or private WiFi?

Tags: windows, wifi

I need to detect if my Windows 10 application is running on a public or private WIFI network. I need to warn the user that he/she is connected to a public network and the connection is susceptible to snooping etc.

On a Windows 10 machine, you can see the WiFi connection type by Settings -> Network and Internet -> Change connection properties. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOAgW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify what language the application is written in. If it is in C# you could probably use the NetworkInformationPermissionAttribute Class.

Comment: Thanks for your response...

I am using C# in an UDP application. 

How to get hold of this attribute?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation?view=net-5.0  OR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinformationpermissionattribute?view=net-5.0 One of these two links should help with your task.

Comment: Thanks. Will checkout those links.